# Having an issue with IIS 8.5 php

Tags: php, iis, iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2

Im having a problem that I installed asp.net and that stuff and php on IIS 8.5
But when I'm trying using PHP I get this

[image]

Is there any way I can fix this so it will run PHP?

I have Windows Server 2012 R2.

Comment: Is that for all PHP files of just `info.php`?

Comment: its for all php files @chris85